# angularjs : custom directive with isolated scope and passing argument

Tags: angularjs

I made a custom directive in angularjs with an isolated scope and passing argument.
I try to check the argument in the controller/link of the directive because some times the argument is an array and i need only one item. but this don't work ( undefined object ).

### - my directive :

```
directives.directive('dir.displaytaxoname',  function () {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace: true,
       scope: {
          dfamily: '@' ,
          dgenus: '@',
          dsn: '@'               
       },
       controller: function ($scope) {

          console.log($scope.dsn); // empty string in the console but ok in the rendered view 
          /*function tools_isArray(arr) { return ( arr instanceof Array ); }*/
          // if the dfamily argument is an array i just want the first item 
          if(tools_isArray($scope.dfamily)){ $scope.dfamily = $scope.dfamily[0]; }
          if(tools_isArray($scope.dgenus)){ $scope.dgenus = $scope.dgenus[0]; }
          if(tools_isArray($scope.dsn)){ cl("indsn") ;  $scope.dsn = $scope.dsn[0]; }
       },
       templateUrl: "partials/elements/displaytaxoname.html"
    }
 });
```

### - my templete :

```
<span>
    {{dfamily}}&nbsp;<i ng-show="dgenus!=''">{{dgenus}}&nbsp;</i><i>{{dsn}}</i><br>
</span>
```

### - call to the directive :

```
<dir.displaytaxoname dfamily="{{specimen['T_FAMILY']}}" 
                     dgenus="{{specimen['T_GENUS']}}" 
                     dsn="{{specimen['T_SCIENTIFICNAME']}}">
</dir.displaytaxoname>
```

I try many combinaison with link/controller but don't work. 
How can i do please ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass non-string values to your directive, you need to bind directly to outer-scope expressions, not to attribute values ([see documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)), because attribute value is always a `String`.

Additionally, if you're not 100% sure the data will already by present on the outer scope when the directive is compiled, you need to `$watch` the data instead of just using the initial values.

```
scope: {
    dfamily: '=',    // bind to expression instead of attribute value
    // ...
},
controller: function ($scope) {
    // watch property value changes instead of using just the initial value
    $scope.$watch('dfamily', function (value) {
        if (tools_isArray(value)) {
            // be extremely careful not to create an infinite cycle here
            // (better save the modified values to different variables)
            $scope.dfamily = value[0];
        }
    });
    // ...
}
```

and

```
<tag dfamily="specimen['T_FAMILY']" ...></tag>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I still get undefined value in the controller if i log ( not in the html view ). sometimes the parameters  are array and sometime a string.

Comment: i still get undefined maybe because the data i use in the directive call come from an asyncronus call to elasticsearch

Comment: thank you, with $watch it work. i post a complete answer merged with your's bellow

Answer (score 1):

You have tested with = ?

```
scope: {
          dfamily: '=' ,
          dgenus: '=',
          dsn: '='               
       }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I still get undefined value in controller.

Answer (score 0):

[complete working solution based on @hon2a answer]

this is a directive with isolated scope who take an array in parameter.
it use $watch because the array parameter is provided after an asynchronus call in the main controller

### - main controller :

```
// in a asynchronus call to elasticsearch
  elasticsearch.search({
     index: $index,
     size:1,
     body: {
        "query": $query
     }
  }).then(function (response) {
     $scope.specimen = response.hits.hits[0]["_source"];
     $scope.taxonamedata = {
        "T_FAMILY" : $scope.specimen["T_FAMILY"] ,
        "T_GENUS": $scope.specimen["T_GENUS"],
        "T_SCIENTIFICNAME": $scope.specimen["T_SCIENTIFICNAME"], //scientific name
        "D_IDENTIFIEDBY": $scope.specimen["D_IDENTIFIEDBY"],
        "D_CREATED":$scope.specimen["D_CREATED"]
     } ;
   }
....
```

### - call to the directive :

```
<dir.displaytaxoname data="taxonamedata"></dir.displaytaxoname>
```

### - the directive :

```
 directives.directive('dir.displaytaxoname',  function ($filter) {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
         data: '='
      },
      controller: function ($scope) {
         // watch property value changes instead of using just the initial value
         $scope.display = "";
         $scope.$watch('data', function (value) {
            if(tools_defined(value)){
               var tmp = value; // copy it to tmp variable to avoid loop when change
               for (var v in tmp) {
                  if (tools_isArray(tmp[v])) { // convert all the array to string
                     tmp[v] = tmp[v][0];
                  }
               }
               $scope.display = tmp["T_FAMILY"] + '&nbsp;';
               if (tools_defined(tmp["T_GENUS"])) {
                  $scope.display += '<i>' + tmp["T_GENUS"] + '</i>&nbsp;';
               }
               if (tools_defined(tmp["T_SCIENTIFICNAME"])) {
                  $scope.display += '<i>' + tmp["T_SCIENTIFICNAME"] + '</i><br>';
               }
               $scope.display += tmp["D_IDENTIFIEDBY"] ;
               if (tools_defined(tmp["D_CREATED"])) {
                  $scope.display +=  '&nbsp;('+$filter('date')(tmp["D_CREATED"], "dd/MM/yyyy")+')';
               }
            }

         });
      },
      plain:true,
      template: '<span ng-bind-html="display | unsafe"></span>'
   }
});
```

### - the unsafe filter who display hmtl :

```
interfaceApp.filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
   return function (val) {
       return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
   };
});
```

---

```
function tools_isArray(arr) {
   return ( arr instanceof Array );
}

function tools_defined(object){
   return (( typeof object != undefined) && ( typeof object != "undefined") && ( object != null ) ) ;
}
```